# “'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: … this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key scoreArray ”

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

```
NSMutableArray * scoreArray = [[[[returnedArr objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"Questionnaire_Answers__r"] valueForKey:@"records"] valueForKey:@"Score__c"];

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        answerArray = [[[NSSet setWithArray:answerArray] allObjects]  mutableCopy];
          NSArray *filteredArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:answerArray];

          NSSortDescriptor *valueDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"scoreArray" ascending:NO]; // Describe the Key value using which you want to sort.
          NSArray * descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:valueDescriptor]; // Add the value of the descriptor to array.
          answerArray = [[filteredArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors] mutableCopy]; // Now Sort the Array using descriptor.

        [self.tblview reloadData];
    });
```

I am trying this code for sorting but I am getting crash.

Comment: show us your scoreArray data.

Comment: @Mahesh my score array data is 3,
1,
2,
4,
0

Comment: It seems you don't understand how sort descriptors work: The **key** is not the variable name of the array, it's a key of the dictionaries or a property of the custom class **in** the array. And do not use `valueForKey:` unless you know what the KVC method does.

Comment: First Debug the code and find where your code is Crush ?

Comment: @VerveIOS it is getting crash on because of initwithkey @"scoreArray"

Comment: Give me your all array value

Comment: What is value of "answerArray" ?

Answer (score -2):

```
NSSortDescriptor *valueDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"scoreArray" ascending:NO];
```

**initWithKey:** it means the model's var, not is array's name.